# Displaying recent buyers' feedback on games

Tags: php

I have the following code made to output the following:

[image: 1]

Is there an efficient way to simplify it and not have to repeat the same `if(!empty($st[$i]['feedback'])) {` code block 2 times just to seperate 2 feedback lines with a `echo '</div><br><div class="row center">';`?

```
<?php

//Get 4 Feedback from Database;
$st = fetch("SELECT username,feedback,feedback_type,feedback_date FROM purchases WHERE feedback IS NOT NULL AND game = :game AND platform = :platform ORDER BY feedback_date DESC LIMIT 4","unfed_payments",array(":game"=>$urlname,":platform"=>$platform));

echo '<div class="row center">';

//Output the first 2 Feedback on line 1;
for($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++) {

    if(!empty($st[$i]['feedback'])) {

        echo '
        <div class="col-lg-6 center">
            <div class="col-sm-12 center" style="width: initial; background-color: ';

            if($st[$i]['feedback_type'] == '+') { echo '#1AB394;"'; } else { echo 'red;"'; };

            echo '>
                <h2 style="font-size: 30px; color: #fff;">';
                    echo $st[$i]['feedback'].'
                </h2>
            </div>
        </div>';

    }

}

echo '</div><br><div class="row center">';

//Output the last 2 Feedback on line 2;
for($i = 2; $i < 4; $i++) {

    if(!empty($st[$i]['feedback'])) {

        echo '
        <div class="col-lg-6 center">
            <div class="col-sm-12 center" style="width: initial; background-color: ';

            if($st[$i]['feedback_type'] == '+') { echo '#1AB394;"'; } else { echo 'red;"'; };

            echo '>
                <h2 style="font-size: 30px; color: #fff;">';
                    echo $st[$i]['feedback'].'
                </h2>
            </div>
        </div>';

    }

}

echo '</div>';

?>
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Simple Approach**

The simplest thing to remove copy-pasted code is to extract the exact duplication to its own function. Any variables that are needed can be passed on:

```
function printFeedback($st, $i) {
    if(!empty($st[$i]['feedback'])) {

        echo '
        <div class="col-lg-6 center">
            <div class="col-sm-12 center" style="width: initial; background-color: ';

            if($st[$i]['feedback_type'] == '+') { echo '#1AB394;"'; } else { echo 'red;"'; };

            echo '>
                <h2 style="font-size: 30px; color: #fff;">';
                    echo $st[$i]['feedback'].'
                </h2>
            </div>
        </div>';

    }
}
```

Then use it:

```
$st = fetch([...]);

echo '<div class="row center">';

//Output the first 2 Feedback on line 1;
for($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++) {
    printFeedback($st, $i);
}

echo '</div><br><div class="row center">';

//Output the last 2 Feedback on line 2;
for($i = 2; $i < 4; $i++) {
    printFeedback($st, $i);
}

echo '</div>';
```

Now the duplication is gone.

**Further Improvements**

Now, the simple approach did remove the direct duplication, but we still have two similar for loops, and we have a function that accepts arguments that do not have real meaning in that context.

Let's improve it further by adjusting our print feedback function:

```
// echoes the given feedback array inside HTML.
function printFeedback($feedback) {
    if($feedback['feedback'])) {

        echo '
        <div class="col-lg-6 center">
            <div class="col-sm-12 center" style="width: initial; background-color: ';

            if($feedback['feedback_type'] == '+') { echo '#1AB394;"'; } else { echo 'red;"'; };

            echo '>
                <h2 style="font-size: 30px; color: #fff;">';
                    echo $feedback['feedback'].'
                </h2>
            </div>
        </div>';

    }
}
```

Personally, I would create a real feedback object, but for this example I have kept it as an array, which may be fine for your purposes.

Now we can use this function in a more generic function:

```
// echoes the feedbacks in the feedback starting at position "from" and going to position "to" (exclusive).
function printFeedbackFromTo(Array $feedbacks, $from, $to) {
    for($i = $from; $i < $to; $i++) {
        printFeedback($feedbacks[$i]);
    }
}
```

And then use that function:

```
$st = fetch([...]);

echo '<div class="row center">';

printFeedbackFromTo(0,2);

echo '</div><br><div class="row center">';

printFeedbackFromTo(2,4);

echo '</div>';
```

**Misc**

- Feedback seems to be user-supplied, so you have to HTML encode it, to prevent XSS.
- Your comments are not needed. Just extract code into properly named functions, possibly with proper function comments (ideally using PHPDoc). In-code comments should not be used to structure your code - use functions for that - but to point out possible unclarities, problems, etc that could not be resolved otherwise.
- The functions you might want to consider would be `getFeedbacks($connection, $amountOfFeedbacks)` and `echoFeedbacks($feedbacks)`.
- Don't put your style info in a style attribute, but in an external CSS file

Comment: Wow, Was not expecting such a huge review! Highly appreciate it but I have a few questions. In the FromTo how is the `function printFeedbackFromTo(Array $feedbacks, $from, $to) {` "Array $feedbacks" working?

Comment: Also in the PrintFeedback function where are you getting: `if($feedback['feedback'])) {` I need the feedback's to be received from the Database. How do I add this?

Comment: Nevermind I worked it out. There are a few issues with your examples like an extra ) and such but I worked it out. As for the Misc, Could you explain how this is XSS vulnerable? To me it doesn't look vulnerable at all. As for the Comments I have to I dont know why but I hate looking at code where every few lines arent commented on what they do. Its kinda just how I read it, I like green o.o I updated your code a bit so I technically have GetFeedbacks now. I never put it into a Style attribute I only do it while I test what it looks like in Inspect Element.

Comment: The updated code of your example is in my OP. Feel free to copy and paste it as your answer. Thanks a ton for putting such a good amount of effort into your answer!

Comment: @ShinyMK `array` is just hinting at the type (accidentally upper-cased it).  The data in the database comes from user input, right (it is feedback after all)? So when you just echo it, without encoding, you are vulnerable to persistent XSS. And I get the commenting to structure code, I used to do it a lot as well. But almost always, it's a sign that you need more functions or classes (or better names for them), not more comments. If you eg have a call `printFeedbackFromTo(feedback, 2,4)`, a comment saying `prints feedback from 2 to 4` is just not necessary anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Tim's answer is very good but have you also considered not echoing out the feedback immediately? If you put it into a variable or use some output buffering you'll be able to manage your output with a lot more flexibility. Generally it's better practice to put all your output in one place rather than having output in functions and objects all over the place. It's much easier to maintain that way, and easier to read (think MVC).

Comment: I actually dont need it to be in a variable as im not storing it or anything like that. its basically a simple GET request (Kind Of) to the Database to output 4 of the Most Recent feedback. I can very easilly do that but there really isnt any need i'm not editing or moving the code etc all I need is to output it.